# class btn btn-primary of twitter bootstrap not working in ie7 ie8 ie9?

Tags: internet-explorer, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have used twitter bootstrap in my project and used classes btn btn-primary btn-warning etc over li elements, but the classes do not apply on ie7 ie8 ie9.

I understand that they might not work on ie7 and ie8 because of lack of support of css3 but i am not sure why its not working in ie9.

Does anyone has some insight into it.

Comment: It works fine in IE8 on our site. 1. What version of Bootstrap are you using? 2. Is it possible you're overwriting the bootstrap styling of this button somewhere?

Comment: Bootstrap 2.3.2 is supported in IE7 and Bootstrap 3 is supported in IE8, but it's in preview at the moment so not everything may work.

Comment: I am using 2.3.1 version

Comment: So it's supposed to work. Try inspecting these buttons to so what overrides the btn-primary styling

Comment: [So the buttons look fine](http://www.browserstack.com/screenshots/737798525312e3f85c01b114a4dbcc2bd1cf8205)

Comment: Could you show your code?

Comment: Its so strange that what was working in Chrome was not working ie browsers, All i had was a li {background-color:white} in a css and i applied <li class='btn'> In chrome the class btn was applied while in ie background-color:white was applied, thanks for your comments @ItayItai yes it was some sort of override but not sure why.

Comment: It's probably a simple difference in the CSS priorities of these two browsers